# Получение указателя на функцию, находящуюся в структуре

Tags: c++, указатели, структуры

Есть структура `JNIEnv` с нестатической функцией `GetStaticMethodID`, и экземпляр этой структуры с именем `g_env`.
Есть функция `MH_CreateHook`, принимающая `LPVOID`. 
Нужно передать в `MH_CreateHook` адрес на `GetStatiMethodID`. Как-либо изменить `JNIEnv` или `MH_CreateHook` нет возможности.

Попытки:

`MH_CreateHook(g_env->GetStaticMethodID)` -

> 'JNIEnv_::GetStaticMethodID': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a
>   pointer to member

`MH_CreateHook(&g_env->GetStaticMethodID)` -

> '&': illegal operation on bound member function expression

`MH_CreateHook((LPVOID)&g_env->GetStaticMethodID)` -

> cannot convert from 'jmethodID (__cdecl JNIEnv_::* )(jclass,const char
>   ,const char )' to 'LPVOID'

Comment: Но вы же понимаете, что если даже вам удастся передать каким то чудом адрес этой функции, то когда хук сработает он вызовет вашу функцию с this абсолютно не g_env и вообще это this скорее всего будет указывать на объект какого то совершенно иного класса (если вы перехватываете вызов члена класса конечно). тогда какой смысл в классе и его экземпляре g_env

Comment: А какую тут можно альтернативу придумать?

Comment: Ну это смотря как вызов идет. Последний раз когда тут задавали вопросы про хуки там как раз перехватывали член класса. Откомпилен он был с fastcall, т.е. часть параметров передавалась в регистрах. В том случае делали обычную функцию никакого отношения к классам не имеющую и в начале у нее делали `mystruct *T; asm { mov T,esi }; потому как this при fastcall передается именно в esi. Так что надо дизассемблировать перехватываемую функцию, смотреть как она получает this и писать соотв. asm вставку, ну или не писать, а правильно параметры объявить, если передача в стеке идет

Answer (score 3):

Нестатический метод класса первым параметром(неявно) принимает указатель на объект. Поэтому в общем случае Ваша задача не решается. Можно, правда, немного «обмануть систему»: создать глобальный объект `JNIEnv`, затем создать функцию(вне классов), которая будет вызывать Ваш метод, к примеру:

```
JNIEnv g_Env;
...
void function()
{
    g_Env.GetStaticMethodID();
}
```

А затем, передать уже адрес function в `MH_CreateHook`:

```
MH_CreateHook(&function);
```

Comment: В этом нет смысла, т.к. мне нужен адрес именно на GetStaticMethodID

Comment: @Plasticable, тогда принимайте первую часть ответа: это невозможно

Answer (score 2):

Правильный синтаксис получения указателя на не статическую функцию-член класса - это

```
&JNIEnv::GetStaticMethodID
```

Но указатели на члены класса - это не обычные указатели, у них может быть больший размер (до `4*sizeof(void*)`), и их нельзя приводить к `void*`.

Comment: Я же писал, что функция не статическая